# Create parent/child relationship in class

Tags: oop, pascal, paradigms, delphi

I have two classes, a child class:

```
type MyChildClass = class
public
parent: ^MyParent;
end;
```

And a parent class:

```
type MyParentClass = class
public
childs: array of ^MyChildClass;
end;
```

However, this wont work since only the class declared the last knows the other one. Example:

```
program Test;

interface

type MyChildClass = class
public
parent: ^MyParentClass;
end;

type MyParentClass = class
public
childs: array of ^MyChildClass;
end;

implementation

end.
```

This wont compile because the 7th line will throw the error "Undeclared identifier 'MyParentClass' as expected. Using abstract classes only solves the problem partially. Im really struggling on finding a solution. Maybe using interfaces would help?

Comment: [Forward declaration](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)#Forward_Declarations_and_Mutually_Dependent_Classes) is what you're missing. Except that, you can declare those field types not like pointers (by removing those `^` operators). And we're using `T` prefix for `T`ype declarations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was it!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: FWIW, do not use pointer syntax for parent or children. In Delphi, class instance  variables are references already. More about this in my article about pointers (and references): [Addressing pointers -- References](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html#references).

Comment: @rudy I know that the extra level of indirection isn't likely to be correct here, and is likely based on a misunderstanding. But it isn't too hard to construct scenarios where pointer to reference makes sense. So perhaps a less absolute instruction would be preferable.

Comment: @David: I meant in this situation, hence the mention of parent and children. So I think what I wrote is correct.

Comment: @rudy With that clarification it is reasonable advice.

Comment: @David: well thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pascal is a single pass-compiled language, therefore the compiler scans only once a single file: in every moment it has to know each identifier. When you are creating a circular reference, like in this case, you are referencing a class written *after* the current one which is not permitted. To fix this issue, you need to use the so called **forward declaration**, i.e. you are declaring (promising) to the compiler that somewhere in your code it will find this identifer (look at the code, *problem1*).

Additionally, you are defining multiple different type scopes (by writing **type** multiple times). Each type scope has it's own types (and a type defined in a scope cannot be seen by another scope), hence, you need to define a single one (look at the code, *problem2*).

```
program Test;

interface

type // declare a single type scope (problem 2)
    MyParentClass = class; // this is the forward declaration (problem 1)

    MyChildClass = class
    public
        parent: ^MyParentClass;
    end;

    MyParentClass = class
    public
        childs: array of ^MyChildClass;
    end;

implementation

end.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
program Test;

interface
type 
    MyParentClass = class;

    MyChildClass = class
    public
        parent: ^MyParentClass;
    end;

    MyParentClass = class
    public
        childs: array of ^MyChildClass;
    end;

implementation

end.
```

Comment: I would up-vote this answer if you had explained what you actually did.

Comment: As @Jerry already said, please explain **why** your code "works", i.e. why you do what you do. Then this would be a good answer. Just posting code is not enough. You can edit your answer and add some explanations.

Comment: What a pitty you chose not to explain your answer.